# Using CData ODBC connection with the DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I have been trying to configure a DocuSign ODBC ( using CData) and came across an issue when trying to get the OAuth credentials.

Based on the Help guide, I see that I need to “Register your DocuSign app”. I am in the API and Keys section on DocuSign but the add app/ integration key button is not there.

Do I need the DocuSign Enterprise plan in order to use this software. This would be an extra cost on our current plan, so I just wanted to make sure first if we need the additional plan to use the ODBC.

https://www.cdata.com/drivers/docusign/odbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you create a developer sandbox (also known as "demo") account? that should have all that you need. You can do that in https://developers.docusign.com

Comment: Yeah i wasnt sure if that would be the solution. Can i add that to the existing DocuSign account. Or just create a new one with the same email?

Comment: new one as this is a different environment

Comment: Alright, so I was able to set up a sandbox account and get a connection with the ODBC driver that way. I now need to create the app and have it reviewed so that I can get the connection to our live environment. I don't really have any knowledge of where I should go about in creating this "app" or APIs in general, and just really need to create it for the Oauth. Is there a simple code I can run that will pass the 20 transactions and the rest of the review requirements?

Comment: First, glad you got this working. Please mark this answered if you don't mind.
as for your question, I recommend getting sample code  from https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/v2/code-examples and see if you get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this. Looking at it, i am guessing I cannot use the QuickStart method because that uses the Token generator?

Comment: you could generate tokens yourself with your own Integration Key instead, the rest of the code can remain the same.